# Bootstrap typeahead - How to set the default value manually

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

I tried this:

```
$("#typeahead_object").val("test");
```

It only changes the textbox value but doesn't trigger the 'updater' function of the typeahead.

**Question :** How can I set the value of a typeahead object manually and trigger its updater function?

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead

Answer (score 15):

To change typeahead input value, use the following construction:

```
$(input).typeahead('val',value);
```

So, in your case it should looks like:

```
$("#typeahead_object").typeahead('val',"test");
```

typeahead API documentation is available on https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets

Comment: after testing meny more finally your one helps me ... thanks Andrew for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could manually trigger a `keyup` event on the input element, after setting the value:

```
$("#typeahead_object").val('test').focus().trigger('keyup')
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I tried it out and what it does is show the list of 'options'.

Comment: Try triggering the change event then: `$('input[data-provide="typeahead"]').val('test').trigger('change')`

Answer (score 1):

As of typeahead.js 0.10.5, this works :

`$('#typeahead_object').typeahead('val', 'some value').blur()`