# Selected item on Bootstrap dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website with Bootstrap framework. I have two very nasty input fields I'm stuck with, because I can't get them to work properly...

One is this Bootstrap Typeahead input field:

```
<input type="text" id="typeahead" name='name' placeholder='The name' class="form-control" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" />
```

The other is this dropdown list:

```
<div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="dates-dropdown-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <?=$reminder_table_th_date?>
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="name-dates-dropdown">
              </ul>
</div>
```

(the `<li>` list is populated via Ajax call)

With both I want to do: if I select one item either on the ajax dropdown field with the typeahead or with the dropdown list the selected item should be the value what the field is showing. I tried many-many ways, for example:

[How to Display Selected Item in Bootstrap Button Dropdown Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437446/how-to-display-selected-item-in-bootstrap-button-dropdown-title)

[Bootstrap 3 dropdown select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662150/bootstrap-3-dropdown-select)

[Bootstrap typeahead - How to set the default value manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309322/bootstrap-typeahead-how-to-set-the-default-value-manually)

but none of them is working and I don't know why. I'm not a JS/jQuery guru at all, but that's just suspicious. Where exactly should I place the jQuery code for this functions and how?

PS: Firefox Firebug isn't showing any JS errors, they just don't do anything, the values aren't set OR the function for them isn't called.

This is the jQuery code for the typeahead Ajax call, the dropdown population (this is working well) and there is also one line where the typeahead value should be set (in the updater), but sadly that's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/functions/name-autocomplete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            success: function(data) {
              process(data);
            }
          });
        },
        displayText: function(item) {
            return item
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            $('#typeahead').typeahead('val', item);
            $.ajax({
            url: '/functions/name-dates-autocomplete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: 'query=' + item,
            success: function(data) {
              $('#name-dates-dropdown').html(data);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: *the selected item should be the value what the field is showing* could you elaborate a bit more on this ?

Comment: Sure. The input text field should set this as VALUE, the dropdown list as selected item, so replace the value what is right now one PHP variable: <?=$reminder_table_th_date?>

Comment: In order to set the <li /> element as selected we need to identify the element. A sample of the `<li>` returned by would be useful

Comment: <li>
<a href="#">February 27.</a>
</li>

Comment: but how is this associated with the typeahead text or the  `<?=$reminder_table_th_date?>` ? How can i say that "February 27" is what i want to mark as selected ?

Comment: "How can i say that "February 27" is what i want to mark as selected " because you click on it... If I click on this element, then this is the SELECTED one. I have two separated field. One is the ajax dropdown on the typeahead and the other is the dropdown list. I think you misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Display the selected item on Bootstrap dropdown list

In order to handle selections on a bootstrap dropdown list, you can bind an click event handler to the **ul.dropdown-menu element**.

This enables you to capture click events from the nested **li** elements as well, which  can in fact be treated as selection events.

Assume this html structure:

```
<div>
    <input type="text"
        id="typeahead"
        name="date"
        placeholder="date"
        class="form-control"
        data-provide="typeahead"
        autocomplete="off" />
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
    id="dates-dropdown-button" type="button"
    data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <!-- Placeholder for the selected th date -->
        <span class="selection"><?=$reminder_table_th_date?></span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="name-dates-dropdown">
        <li>12.11.97</li>
        <li>10.01.07</li>
        <li>2.11.2017</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can handle selection on a bootstrap dropdown list with 
this event handler:

```
// handles selections on a bootstrap dropdown list
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function (e) {
    var isLITag = e.target && e.target.tagName == 'LI';
    if (isLITag) {
        var selectedValue = $(e.target).text();
        $('#typeahead').typeahead('val', selectedValue);
        // Specifies the display value of the dropdown element
        $('.dropdown-toggle .selection').text(selectedValue);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

### 2. Typeahead value

I think there is a problem how you assign the datasource to the typeahead only the second parameter accepts a [datasources](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadoptions-datasets). Furthermore typeahead.js provides a richer data source implementations called [Bloodhound](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md), it is worth to consider.

I created a demo that makes use of the bloodhound data source. It also demonstrates how to specifies the value of typeahead and how you can handle typeahead selections.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Constructs the suggestion engine with a set of local dummy dates.
  var dateSet = {
    name: 'dates',
    display: 'date',
    source: new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('date'),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      local: [{
          'date': '12.11.97',
          'id': 0
        }, {
          'date': '2.11.2017',
          'id': 1
        }, {
          'date': '10.01.07',
          'id': 2
        }]
        /**
         * In order to integrate your ajax call
         * replace the local attribute with:
         *
         * remote: {
         *   url: '/functions/name-autocomplete.php?query=%QUERY',
         *   wildcard: '%QUERY'
         * }
         *
         * Twitter provides a list of examples at:
         *  http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/
         *
         */
    })
  };

  // Creates the typeahead and assign the dateSet.
  $('#typeahead').typeahead({
    minLength: 1
  }, dateSet);

  // The selection handler sets the value for the drop down-menu
  // whenever a suggestion is chosen.
  $('#typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, selection) {
    $('.dropdown-menu').val(selection.date);
    $('.dropdown-toggle .selection').text(selection.date);
  });

  // handles selections on a bootstrap dropdown list
  $('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
    var isLITag = e.target && e.target.tagName == 'LI';
    if (isLITag) {
      var selectedValue = $(e.target).text();
      $('#typeahead').typeahead('val', selectedValue);
      //Specifies the display value of the dropdown element
      $('.dropdown-toggle .selection').text(selectedValue);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tt-menu {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border-radius: 9px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
  
<div>
  <input type="text"
         id="typeahead"
         name='name'
         placeholder='Serach for ...'
         class="form-control"
         data-provide="typeahead"
         autocomplete="off" />
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
          id="dates-dropdown-button" type="button"
          data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <!-- Placeholder for the selected th date -->
    <span class="selection"><?=$reminder_table_th_date?></span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="name-dates-dropdown">
    <li>12.11.97</li>
    <li>10.01.07</li>
    <li>2.11.2017</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I placed this code (in the section 1.) at the end of my <body> inside $(document).ready(function()) but still nothing happens after I click on the elements :(

Comment: Have you placed a <span class="selection"><?=$reminder_table_th_date?></span> element inside button.dropdown-toggle? This is required in order to display the current selection.

Comment: Yes, the dropdown look like now this: <button id="dates-dropdown-button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="selection">Selected text</span>
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>