# How to show default value in the toogle dropdown menu?

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I have created the dropdown which has 2 values:
1) `Value1`
2) `Value2`

I want to select `Value1` as the default value in dropdown.
I have created the following but it is only hard coding the `Value1` and not redirecting to `Value1`

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="margin-right:10px;">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"
            id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Value1
        <span class="caret"> </span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" ng-model="auditToggle">
        <li><a ng-click="methodName('/method1')">Value1</a> </li>
        <li><a ng-click="methodName('/method2')">Value2</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578745/selected-item-on-bootstrap-dropdown-list

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<ul>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<li [value]="'Value1'"><a ng-click="methodName('/method1')">Value1</a> </li>
<li [value]="'Value2'"><a ng-click="methodName('/method2')">Value2</a> </li>
```