# How to set selected value of typeahead

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

how can i set a default value in typeahead .
i tried many solutions here, but no one seems to work .

Like `tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", 'deafulttag');`

Below is my whole code .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tagApi = $(".tm-input").tagsManager();
    jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead({
        name: 'job_skill',
        displayKey: 'category',
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.get('ajaxpro.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                return process(data);
            });
        },
        afterSelect :function (item){
            tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", item);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help .

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-fill the element with a value?

```
jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead('val',"test");
```

Source: [Bootstrap typeahead - How to set the default value manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309322/bootstrap-typeahead-how-to-set-the-default-value-manually)

Edit:

In your example you'd want to initiate typeahead with this value something like below rather than re-initialising it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tagApi = $(".tm-input").tagsManager();
    jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead({
        name: 'job_skill',
        displayKey: 'category',
        val: 'test',
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.get('ajaxpro.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                return process(data);
            });
        },
        afterSelect :function (item){
            tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", item);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: not working , i put the above line in bottom , nothing changes .

Comment: See above edit in case you copy-pasted the line from above